# Getting the Implemented Interfaces in a Class

Tags: vb.net, interface

Is there a way to get a reference for each of the interfaces implemented in a class?

For example, I have a class;

```
Class ExampleClass1
    Implements IInterfaceI
    Implements IInterface2

End Class
```

Can I get a reference to each interface, so that I may store it for use in another class?

```
Class ExampleClass2

    Private interface1Implementer as IInterface1
    Private interface2Implementer as IInterface2

End Class
```

And when I call the methods in each interface, it calls the methods implemented by ExampleClass1?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use:

```
Dim Instance As New ExampleClass1()
Dim Interface1Implementer As IInterface1 = Instance 
Dim Interface2Implementer As IInterface2 = Instance
```